# How to programmatically set cell.textLabel.text from a different view?

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, uitableview

I've got a view controller, call it VC1, that's a table view. When I tap a cell in the table view, I am presented with a new view controller, call it VC2, which is a short list of choices. After making a choice, I want to dismiss VC2 and set the cell.textLabel.text property of the VC1 cell I originally tapped to the value I selected in VC2.

Conceptually speaking, what is the proper way to do this? I've tried a handful of different approaches, but all of them seem wonky at best, and only one of them actually worked - although it was the most cumbersome of all, passing references to both view controllers and table view cells and all kinds of things. It just feels like I'm making a mountain out of what is probably a mole hill.

This is such a common paradigm that I find it hard to believe there's not a simple method for doing it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I do kind of that with with a table view presenting several attributes of an data object. To change a single attribute the user has to select the specific table cell showing the  attribute he wants to change and that will push a new view controller (with a picker in my case) where the user can change the value from a selection.

I assign the data object to a property of the new controller before pushing. With this the value can be changed directly in the data object, and when i return (via navigation controller) to the first view controller there is a reloadData in viewWillAppear.

Did you try it this way?

Comment: the 'reloadData' part is what I was missing; when I added that, the world was right again.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

There are a number of ways to handle this but one of the most flexible is via the **Delegate Pattern**. Define a delegate protocol in VC2's interface and then make VC1 conform to that protocol. When you create VC2 assign VC1 as it's delegate (similar to the way you did with your `UITableView`). One requirement of your protocol should be a method like `didFinishWithStringSelection:` (or whatever you call it) where you would update the table cell and `reloadTable`.